# Can a finite dimensional topological space have no subspace with finite Lebesgue covering dimension

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

I wonder if it's possible for a topological space $(M, \tau)$ where $\tau$ is the collection of all open subsets of $M$, to have a finite Lebesgue covering dimension, while having no proper subspace of finite (but nonzero) dimension. Especially if such space is not Hausdorff and not locally Euclidean.

I am curious about the case in which the set $M$ doesn't have any isolated point.

Comment: "None zero" = "nonzero"? "Subspace"="proper subspace"?

Comment: Yes @MoisheKohan

Comment: Take 2-point set with nontrivial, non-Hausdorff topology.

Comment: But this is the anti-discrete topology, I'm more interested in a more general case. @MoisheKohan

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "antidiscrete" and "more general" but this is an example. If you do not like it you have to edit your question to explain what are the exact properties you want this topology to have.

Comment: Is the topology you mean: $\tau=\{ \phi, \{a\}, \{a, b\} \}$? @MoisheKohan

Comment: Of course, this is the only nontrivial non-Hausdorff topology on $\{a, b\}$ (up to relabeling).

Comment: I add a new constraint that excludes such case. @MoisheKohan

Comment: There are examples with $\dim X=n$ and every subspace of $X$ has dimension either $n$ or $0$ (but those examples have proper $n$ dimensional subspaces)

Comment: I am interested to know about such cases, Especially if they're not locally Euclidean @AlessandroCodenotti